# Как обратиться к элементу созданному в echo?

Tags: php, php7

У меня есть следующий код:

```
echo '<a name="sender" href="">'.$_sender.'</a>';
```

И я бы хотел сделать, чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку выполнялся код. Примерно так:

`if ( isset('sender') ) {
   echo "Всё верно!";
 }`

, но код не работает.

Как через `isset` обратиться к элементу?

Comment: Вам туда: http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?external

Comment: мне кажется вам, для начала, нужно понять принцип работы...например то, что вы пишите на php - это серверная часть.. html,js css - клинетская...ну и так далее ( посмотреть уроки например или почитать книги, статьи)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае средствами php это не делается. Вот пример, как можно реализовать при помощи JS (подключил библиотеку jQuery)

```js
$('.sender').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('.success').html('Всё верно!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="sender" class="sender" href="#">Sender</a>
<div class="success"></div>
```

Comment: Извините, вы меня не правильно мне нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с именем пользователя, показывались бы сообщения отправленные мне от него и ему от меня, как это сделать?

Comment: Это нельзя реализовать одним действием. Если это чистый php, то нужно подключиться к БД. Сделать выборку из таблицы и вывести на экран

Comment: Ну а как мне сделать так чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с именем Петя мне открывалась таблица с сообщениями которые я посылал Пете или он мне, а если я нажму, например, на Васю, то мне откроется таблица с сообщениями от Васи мне и Васе от меня?

Comment: В вашем случае - начать изучать веб программирование. Общий принцип, как это сделать, я вам написал. Более развёрнутого ответа дать не смогу, так как у меня нет никакой информации, как работает ваш сайт